# User status API

Tags: clockify

I would like to get a list of all the active users using API. When I use  :

`GET /workspace/{workspaceId}/users`

I get a list of all the users, I wanted to use their "status" field to filter them out. The problem is all the users have "ACTIVE" status, no matter what their real status is (active or inactive).

I suppose it some sort of bug, right? Or is there some other way to get a list of active users?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a code support Q&A site, this reads more like a product support request. You're better off contacting Clockify through their [official support channels](https://clockify.me/help/).

Answer (score 1):

`status` of user refers to the state in the system, i.e. whether has verified email address or not. It does not refer to the status of the user in any given workspace.

That information can be read from the list of memberships that is returned in the response. Filter the memberships by the id of the workspace and read its `status`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the url would look like this: GET /workspace/{workspaceId}/users?active=true. The web service would handle this query string parameter like below:

```
public List<User> Get(bool active)
{
    var users = GetActiveUsers(); // Call to database which has a query to get only active users.
    return users;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'm almost sure it works :) but I can't try if it works since all of the users in my workspace are considered ACTIVE when I use API, although some of them have been marked as INACTIVE in the web-based interface